# extracting numbers from list

Tags: python, list

I've created a list (which is sorted):

```
indexlist = [0, 7, 8, 12, 19, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33]
```

I want to extract the numbers from this list that are at least five away from each other and input them into another list. This is kind of confusing. This is an example of how I want the output:

```
outlist = [0, 7, 19, 25, 31]
```

As you can see, none of the numbers are within 5 of each other.

I've tried this method:

```
for index2 in range(0, len(indexlist) - 1):
        if indexlist[index2 + 1] > indexlist[index2] + 5:
            outlist.append(indexlist[index2])
```

However, this gives me this output:

```
outlist = [0, 12, 19]
```

Sure, the numbers are at least 5 away, however, I'm missing some needed values.

Any ideas about how I can accomplish this task?

Comment: What do you mean by "five away from each other"? Five what? Positions or value-wise?

Comment: @Andrey Value. check the example, it's quite clear.

Comment: @Andrey   value-wise

Comment: it is because you are comparing two consecutive members of index list. The `if`statement should be comparing the latest addition to `outlist` and iterated element of `indexlist`

Comment: it wasnt wise and i do not understand why I have minus 1 now

Comment: @hadik Yes!! However, I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: you can initialise the `outlist` with first member of your `indexlist` and try to compare next elements with the iterated members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep track of the last item you added to the list, not just compare to the following value:

```
In [1]: indexlist = [0, 7, 8, 12, 19, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33]
In [2]: last = -1000 # starting value hopefully low enough :)
In [3]: resultlist = []
In [4]: for item in indexlist:
   ...:     if item > last+5:
   ...:         resultlist.append(item)
   ...:         last = item
   ...:
In [5]: resultlist
Out[5]: [0, 7, 19, 25, 31]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Here, as I said in comment, the `outlist` is initialised with the first value of `indexlist`and iterated `indexlist` elements are compared to it. It is a rough solution. But works.

```
indexlist = [0, 7, 8, 12, 19, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33]
outlist = [indexlist[0]]

for index2 in range(1, len(indexlist) - 1):
        if indexlist[index2] > (outlist[-1] + 5):
            outlist.append(indexlist[index2])
```

output:

```
>>outlist

[0, 7, 19, 25, 31]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tim Pietzcker's answer is right but this can also be done without storing the last added item in a separate variable. Instead you can read the last value in outlist:

```
>>> indexlist = [0, 7, 8, 12, 19, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33]
>>> outlist = []
>>> for n in indexlist:
...     if not outlist or n > outlist[-1] + 5:
...         outlist.append(n)
...
>>> outlist
[0, 7, 19, 25, 31]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `index_list` is sorted. Then this will give you only indexes `MIN_INDEX_OFFSET` apart.

```
MIN_INDEX_OFFSET = 5;

index_list = [0, 7, 8, 12, 19, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33];
last_accepted = index_list[0];
out_list = [last_accepted];

for index in index_list:
    if index-last_accepted > MIN_INDEX_OFFSET:
    out_list.append(index);
    last_accepted = index;

print(out_list)
```